# Jquery autocomplete with delimited values

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, autocomplete

I'm trying to add auto complete while using 
[jQuery-Autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)
Basing (with some small changes )
[tutorial made by Mykong](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-jquery-autocomplete-example/)

I have spring application which lists all users

One of my controllers intercept url and after this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAccounts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void listAccounts(@RequestParam String name,
    HttpServletResponse response) {
List<Account> all_accounts = accountRepo.findAll();
for (Account account : all_accounts) {
    if (account.toString().contains(name)) {
        try {
            response.getWriter().write(account.toString() + ",");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

It returns page with delimited values for example :

> User Name1, User Name2, User Name3 ...

(I was forced to produce just delimited value because in my already grown application i receive some `getOutputStream exceptions` , but anyway..)

Then I try to add those data as autocomplete suggestions in jsp :

```
$('#contact_person').autocomplete({
serviceUrl : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getAccounts',
paramName : "name",
delimiter : ",",
transformResult : function(response) {
    return{
    suggestions: $.map(response, function(item) {
        return {
            value : item,
            data : item
        };
    })
    };
}
});
```

But this just throws some JQuery error like

**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '79' in ...**

Is there anyway to parse the page result of json first and somehow assign it to autocomplete?

Tried to produce array out of result , but can't then add it as suggestions

Comment: on which line number is the above error popping up ?

Comment: @dreamweiver It causes error in jquery it self: jquery-latest.js:997
in isArraylike( obj ) function :

return type === "array" || type !== "function" &&
  ( length === 0 ||
  typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj );`

Comment: `jquery-latest.js` what sort of jquery lib is this ? custom one ?

Comment: @dreamweiver it came with mvc spring archeatype and was working fine by now :)
https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution a bit other way so want to leave it here if somebody will have some similar problem

It appeared that I was recieving

> getOutputStream exceptions

because tried to add Account entity class as attribute to model which had some OneToMany and ManyToOne relations with other entities. As this relation was not needed for autocomplete, used inner class which had only fields required for me ( name, surname, email)
So now I can parse it to json within js without any problem. Code itself is now :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAccounts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<DisplayAccount> listAccounts(@RequestParam String name,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    List<Account> all_accountr = accountRepo.findAll();
    List<DisplayAccount> result = new ArrayList<DisplayAccount>();
    for (Account account : all_accountr) {
        if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(account.toString(), name)) {
            DisplayAccount s_account = new DisplayAccount(account);
            result.add(s_account);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

and inner class:

```
class DisplayAccount {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private Long id;

    public DisplayAccount(Account account) {
        setId(account.getId());
        setName(account.getName());
        setSurname(account.getSurname());
        setEmail(account.getEmail());
    }
    //...and some getters and setters
```